# Change look of website

Tags: html, google-chrome, cgi

Our office has an email/filing system that is web based (runs on our local servers/intranet) and whilst the functionality is mostly there, it looks like an absolute pig; something that the creators of it appear to have no interest in fixing as it's looked awful for years.

Is there any way I can force the page to load with my own style applied? I use google chrome and have a decent (though not advanced) knowledge of creating web pages.

As far as I can tell, the system doesn't use CSS. I think it's all HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use JavaScript and CSS to add your own style to the pages on load. Chrome has an extension called Tampermonkey that lets users create userscripts, which are scripts run automatically on pages you specify.

If you create your own style, you can use it on the page with a script like this (this is the jQuery function, I'll try to find out how to do it in plain JS):

```
$('head').append("<style>//your style</style>");
```

This should apply the style. If you set the script as a userscript in Tampermonkey, it will run automatically.

Tell me if you would like more details or if I need to be more clear! You can find Tampermonkey at [this link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) on the Chrome store- their website is [here](https://tampermonkey.net/).